# Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ and $c − b = 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that

$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ and $c − b = 1$.

Prove that

1. $a$ is odd,
2. $b$ is divisible by 4,
3. $c \mid a^b + b^a$

Comment: What can you say about the *odd or even* parity of $b$ and $c$?  If you consider the set $R = \{0,1,2,3\}$ of the smallest non-negative residues of an integer, $\pmod{4}$, and if $k \in \Bbb{Z}, r \in R, ~$ such that $k^2 \equiv r\pmod{4}$, then $r$ can take on which of the possible elements in $R$?  For example, is it possible that $k^2 \equiv 2\pmod{4}$?

Comment: Show us your attempts in order to avoid down/close votes, read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: So $a^2 + b^2 = (b+ 1)^2$ and.... it should just fall into place.

Comment: For question 3, use the fact that $c=b+1$ to write $b \equiv 1 \pmod c$ and substitute the obtained expression of $a$ to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert in this but this is how I have attempted this problem. Building on @fleablood you can approach this problem as:
$$a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag{1}$$
We put $c=b+1$ [from the given equation into (1)] and get
$$a^2+b^2=(b+1)^2$$
$$a^2+b^2=b^2+1+2b$$
$$a^2=2b+1\tag{2}$$Name this equation (2)
Now since the condition for $a,b,c\in \mathbb{N}$ is mentioned in the problem you can make a set of values of 'b' which is something like this,
$$b={4,12,24...}$$
This means you Part 2. is solved. And from equation (2) you get part 1. as well.
Since $b$ and $c$ have been found. You can expand the result to $'a'$ and finish the problem.
Hope this helps you!!
Sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: thank you for helping me....

Comment: @SubrahmanyaSastryVempati you may accept this answer if you found it useful. Just click on the tick mark on the left side of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. is already answered, since $a^2=(b+1)^2-b^2=2b+1$, $a$ should be an odd integer.
2. follows from the fact that any odd square number is of the form $8n+1$
   To show this:

Let $a=2m+1$, since $a$ is odd. Now $$\frac{a^2-1}{8}=\frac{{(2m+1)}^2-1}{8}=\frac{m(m+1)}{2} = \text{some positive integer}$$